# Exponentiation with rationals - why algebraic?

Tags: definition

Why is exponentiation with rational numbers considered an algebraic operation? I get why exponentiation with integers is since that's just a finite number of applications of multiplication, but this doesn't extend to roots.

Comment: Where have you heard that it is?

Comment: As I understood it, it is referred to as such in the context of the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelsImpossibilityTheorem.html).

Comment: Probably because the function $x\mapsto x^{1/n}$ defined on $[0,\infty)$ is the reciprocal of the function $x\mapsto x^n$ which is algebraic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is due to the fact they are required for the solution of polynomial equations with rational (or even integer) coefficients, which was the main concern of algebra for several centuries.

Answer (score 3):

This is for historical reasons, the operation $x \mapsto \sqrt[n]{x}$, extracting a ($n$:th) root, is considered algebraic. (And consequently, raising something to a rational number is, too.)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the statement of [Abel's Impossibility Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelsImpossibilityTheorem.html)
that you linked to in a comment.
It says something about a finite number of certain operations
which include multiplication and root extraction
(which in this context means $n$th root, where $n$ is an integer).

Given a number $r$, with a finite number of multiplications you can 
produce $r^m$.  Then take the $n$th root:
$$\sqrt[n]{r^m} = r^{m/n}.$$